# iOS should model objects be able to access network with NSURLSession

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am in the middle of an app re-design and am refactoring and extending my model.

One aspect of my apps model is that the app retrieves data from a web service and populates the model.

**My question is: Should my model objects have the capability to implement NSURLSession or should I rely on the VC to provide the connection?**

I'm asking from a best practices standpoint. What's the best way to think about this? Should the model be totally on its own or should it have network access?

One consideration is that these model objects are essentially useless without data from the network, meaning data from the Internet is a fundamental aspect of their existence.

Comment: I think you need to consider the lifecycle of the objects. If the viewController gets released, do you want the download to continue? If so, the NSURLSession probably shouldn't be attached to the viewController, but perhaps the model or even the application delegate instead.

Comment: If you were to use the appDelegate that would suggest using a centralized approach to download tasks wouldn't it? These downloads are snippets of xml text data and are small in size.

Comment: It depends on your app. If the data is global to the entire app, putting it in appDelegate or a singleton data model object makes sense. If the data is unique to each viewController, it may make sense to put the network code inside those viewControllers or in related dataModel classes. Think about whether you want the downloads to continue when screens are popped, whether you want to cache the data, whether it's unique to one viewController or used throughout the app.

Comment: @EricS the data is unique to the VC. I think that putting networking in the model objects makes sense in my case. In any event, it doesn't sound like its a bad idea in a general sense to allow model objects to network.

Comment: For small snippets that are unique to each viewController, I've seen the download code in both the model and in the viewController. Some think the model is the more correct place, but there are advantages to having it in the viewController too, especially if the model is nothing but a simple NSDictionary. In that case you can avoid having a model object altogether.

Comment: @EricS my model is a little more involved than a simple dictionary. I'm persisting time-sensitive data and presenting the last saved version while downloading an update asynchronously and displaying it, then persisting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we take [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) — especially the S for [Single Responsible Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) — in account, it becomes obvious, that neither the VC nor the model should do the networking:

- a VC's single responsible would be to handle views
- the model's purpose would be to hold data
- networking should be done by a third class, a networking controller.

This three points will fulfill SOLID, but how do you get data from the network into model objects show on a view?

Well, this depends on your overall architectural design on the app, but a common approach would be to use callback — either a delegate protocol or a block — with your network controller.
You create a network controller in the app delegate and pass it from view controller to view controller via properties to any place in the app were newly fetched data is needed. I wouldn't use a singleton here, as that violates O, I & D of SOLID.
Add a class method to your model `+(NSArray *)modelObjectsFromDictionaries:(NSArray *)` or similar.
In the view controller you can now do

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    [self.networkController fetchModels:^(NSArray *modelDictionaries, NSError *error){
        typeof(weakSelf) self = weakSelf;
        if(self) {
            if(!error){
              [self.dataSource addOrUpdateData:[Model modelObjectsFromDictionaries:modelDictionaries]];
            } else {
                // error handling
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

This is just a starting point. For more complicated APIs it might be useful to use an api controller that itself uses the networking controller and maybe a persistence controller.

Although instead of a Model class method you might want to use some sort of mapping and abstract factory pattern… But all this things would require more information about your app and are out of the scope for this question.

---

Update:

I created a sample project to demonstrate this.
It is slightly different than what I say above:
As it uses a table view, I am using a data source class to populate it. Instead of the view controller the data source will tell the network controller to fetch new data.

I am using [OFAPopulator](https://github.com/vikingosegundo/ofapopulator) for this, a library written by me to populate table views and collection views in a SOLID-conform fashion, or to «Keep view controllers clean and MVC smart».

---

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "VSNetworkController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [self.window.rootViewController setValue:[[VSNetworkController alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.goeuro.com/api/v2/"]]
                                      forKey:@"networkController"];
    return YES;
}

@end
```

---

```
//  VSNetworkController.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface VSNetworkController : NSObject
-(instancetype)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *) baseURL;

-(void)suggestionsForString:(NSString *)suggestionString
            responseHandler:(void(^)(id responseObj, NSError *error))responseHandler;
@end
```

---

```
//  VSNetworkController.m


#import "VSNetworkController.h"

@interface VSNetworkController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURL *baseURL;

@end


@implementation VSNetworkController
-(instancetype)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _baseURL = baseURL;
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)suggestionsForString:(NSString *)suggestionString
            responseHandler:(void(^)(id responseObj, NSError *error))responseHandler
{
    NSURL *url = [self.baseURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"position/suggest/en/%@", suggestionString]];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                                               NSData *data,
                                               NSError *connectionError) {
                               responseHandler([NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil], connectionError);
                           }];
}
@end
```

---

```
//  VSLocationSuggestion.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@import CoreLocation;

@interface VSLocationSuggestion : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSString *country;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) CLLocation *position;

+(NSArray *)suggestionsFromDictionaries:(NSArray *)dictionaries;
@end
```

---

```
//  VSLocationSuggestion.m

#import "VSLocationSuggestion.h"

@interface VSLocationSuggestion ()
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *country;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocation *position;
@end

@implementation VSLocationSuggestion
+(NSArray *)suggestionsFromDictionaries:(NSArray *)dictionaries
{
    NSMutableArray *array = [@[] mutableCopy];
    [dictionaries enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary *suggestionDict, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        [array addObject:[[self alloc] initWithDictionary:suggestionDict]];
    }];
    
    return [array copy];
}

-(instancetype)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _name = dict[@"name"];
        _country = dict[@"country"];
        CLLocationDegrees latitude = [dict[@"geo_position"][@"latitude"] doubleValue];
        CLLocationDegrees longitude =[dict[@"geo_position"][@"longitude"] doubleValue];
        _position = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:latitude longitude:longitude];
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

---

```
//  VSSuggestionDataSource.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <OFADataProvider.h>
@class VSNetworkController;
@interface VSSuggestionDataSource : NSObject <OFADataProvider>

-(instancetype)initWithNetworkController:(VSNetworkController *)networkController;
-(void)setNewSuggestions:(NSArray *)suggetsions;

-(void)enteredStringForSuggestions:(NSString *)suggestionString;
@end
```

---

```
//  VSSuggestionDataSource.m

#import "VSSuggestionDataSource.h"
#import "VSNetworkController.h"
#import "VSLocationSuggestion.h"

@interface VSSuggestionDataSource ()
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^available)(void);
@property (nonatomic, strong) VSNetworkController *networkController;
@end


@implementation VSSuggestionDataSource
@synthesize sectionObjects;

-(instancetype)initWithNetworkController:(VSNetworkController *)networkController
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _networkController = networkController;
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)dataAvailable:(void (^)(void))available
{
    _available = available;
}

-(void)setNewSuggestions:(NSArray *)suggetsions
{
    self.sectionObjects = suggetsions;
    self.available();
}

-(void)enteredStringForSuggestions:(NSString *)s
{
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    [self.networkController suggestionsForString:s responseHandler:^(NSArray *responseObj, NSError *error) {
        typeof(weakSelf) self = weakSelf;
        if (self) {
            if (!error && responseObj) {
                NSArray *suggestion = [VSLocationSuggestion suggestionsFromDictionaries:responseObj];
                [self setNewSuggestions:suggestion];
            }
        }
    }];
}


@end
```

---

```
//  ViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class VSNetworkController;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) VSNetworkController *networkController;

@end
```

---

```
//  ViewController.m

#import "ViewController.h"
#import "VSLocationSuggestion.h"
#import <OFAViewPopulator.h>
#import <OFASectionPopulator.h>
#import "VSSuggestionDataSource.h"


@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) OFAViewPopulator *viewPopultor;
@property (strong, nonatomic) VSSuggestionDataSource *dataSource;
- (IBAction)textChanged:(UITextField *)sender;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.dataSource = [[VSSuggestionDataSource alloc] initWithNetworkController:self.networkController];
    
    OFASectionPopulator *sectionPopulator = [[OFASectionPopulator alloc] initWithParentView:self.tableView
                                                                               dataProvider:self.dataSource
                                                                             cellIdentifier:^NSString *(id obj, NSIndexPath *indexPath) {
        return @"Cell";
    } cellConfigurator:^(VSLocationSuggestion *obj, UITableViewCell *cell, NSIndexPath *indexPath) {
        cell.textLabel.text = obj.name;
    }];
    
    sectionPopulator.objectOnCellSelected = ^(VSLocationSuggestion *suggestion, UIView *cell, NSIndexPath *indexPath ){
        NSString * string =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@ (%f %f)", suggestion.name, suggestion.country, suggestion.position.coordinate.latitude, suggestion.position.coordinate.longitude];
        
        UIAlertController *avc = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Selected" message:string preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        
        UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction
                                       actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", @"Cancel action")
                                       style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                                       handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                                       {
                                           ;
                                       }];
        [avc addAction:cancelAction];
        [self presentViewController:avc animated:YES completion:NULL];
    };
    self.viewPopultor = [[OFAViewPopulator alloc] initWithSectionPopulators:@[sectionPopulator]];

}


- (IBAction)textChanged:(UITextField *)sender
{
    NSString *s = sender.text;
    if ([s length]) {
        [self.dataSource enteredStringForSuggestions:s];
    }
}
@end;
```

---

I made this code available on github: https://github.com/vikingosegundo/LocationSugesstion

---

Comment: This is great. How would creating a networkController in the applicationDelegate be accomplished?

Comment: Normal `alloc/init...`ing

Comment: Sure. But you would create it in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions or what?

Comment: For that matter why not just create a class specifically for that purpose instead of monkeying around with singletons or the App Delegate?

Comment: ??? where did I say "use singletons" or "let the app delegate do the networking"?

Comment: Take it easy. I'm asking why not create a class dedicated to networking rather than the solution you describe? You've articulated a well considered answer and I'm asking why not consider a different approach?

Comment: I am writing exactly that: a controller for networking. what would it be if not a class?